# Where can I find my device info?

Tags: android-emulator, system-info

**Disclaimer:** I am not looking for the "General > About device" information.

I am trying to look for the information about the performance, RAM, screen size/dpi for my device, so that  I can create an emulator for app development.

Comment: Look at the manufacturers data sheet or another source like GSMArena.

Answer (score 1):

There are pretty much good app in Google play you can take help from there , search for hardware information or device information application will make your work.

I prefer one of my best app - CPU Z.

Hope it helps.